# Scaling image inside div fails

Tags: html, css

I have got the following structure in HTML:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        <div id="c">
            <img src="http://public.media.smithsonianmag.com/legacy_blog/npg_portraits_nicholson_jack_2002.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in CSS:

```
#a{
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}

#b {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    max-height:100%; /*should be 300px - 2*20px = 260px */
    /*no height shall be set here*/
}

#c {
    background-color:green;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: inherit;
}

img {
    opacity: 0.8;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

I want the image to be scaled into the red container. The structure is kind of fixed that way. I also uploaded the fiddle for you:

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/at0sjfuz/1/)

I hope someone is able to help!

Comment: Tried max-height: 100%; on the img?

Comment: @j08691: yes, i already tried, but it didnt work for me.

Comment: @tellob do you want the image to cover the complete area of the red `<div>`?

Comment: What is the end result here? To have the image scaled within the red container?

Comment: @773: To have the image scale to fit within #c either by max-height or max-width.

Comment: @773: yes this is exactly the aim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaled with `position: absolute` on the image.

- `#a` has `position: relative` and the `position: absolute` image will scale accordingly.
- Centered with the combination of top, right, bottom, left and `margin: auto`
- `box-sizing: border-box` incorporates the padding and any borders into your width and helps prevent that pesky scrollbar

### Example

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#a {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative
}
#b {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 100%;
  /*should be 300px - 2*20px = 260px */
  /*no height shall be set here*/
}
#c {
  background-color: green;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: inherit;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0.8;
  height: 90%;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
    <div id="c">
      <img src="http://public.media.smithsonianmag.com/legacy_blog/npg_portraits_nicholson_jack_2002.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does max-width:180% bring for the image?

Comment: The padding from a is lost! How to get it back?

Comment: Edited. Is `height: calc(100% - 40px);` ok? The image is vertically centered, so we remove 40px and we have a 20px gap above and below.

Comment: Also, above the calc height is `height: 90%`. If the browser doesn't support `calc()` then it will use the 90% height. [Calc is supported in all modern browsers and IE 9+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

Comment: Remember that the image **will not** affect the height of `#b` or `#c` anymore. They will need to have a height of some kind. `height: 100%` would work. It's entirely dependant on what you are trying to achieve :)